# Retaining logicless templates while using conditionals in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine

I'm using the [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) library to make templates for my website. But, because templates should be logicless, basic Boolean logic (e.g. print a red or a green div based on a less-than check) is difficult without resorting to hacks. How can I resolve these kinds of problems without adding logic to my templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logicless** doesn't mean you can't use logic at all, it just means that you can't use logic *in templates*.
You should prepare all of your data before passing it to template.

For example, consider this common use case on an MV* app (like a Backbone-powered app):

Model:

```
{
  name: 'Roger',
  age: 50
}
```

View:

```
...
getTemplateData: function (model) {
  var data = model;

  if (model.age >= 50) {
    data.isTooOld= true;
  }

  return data;
}
...
render: function () {
  var data = this.getTemplateData(model) || {};
  this.el.innerHTML = this.template(data);
}
...
```

Template:

```
<p>
  OK, {{name}},
  {{#if isTooOld}}
    you're too old for this shit!
  {{else}}
    let's do this!
  {{/if}}
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'll use this next time, so far I've been registering custom handlers to make it work, this seems much better!